# iOS, How to do face tracking using the rear camera?

Tags: ios, camera, computer-vision, tracking

I'm planning to use ARKit's camera feed as input into Apple's Vision API so I can recognize people's faces in screen-space, no depth information required. To simplify the process, I'm attempting to modify Apple's face tracking over frames example here: [Tracking the User’s Face in Real Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time)

I thought that I could simply change the function here:

```
 fileprivate func configureFrontCamera(for captureSession: AVCaptureSession) throws -> (device: AVCaptureDevice, resolution: CGSize) {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .front)

        if let device = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first {
            if let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
                if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
                    captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
                }

                if let highestResolution = self.highestResolution420Format(for: device) {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    device.activeFormat = highestResolution.format
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()

                    return (device, highestResolution.resolution)
                }
            }
        }

        throw NSError(domain: "ViewController", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }
```

In the first line of the function, one of the arguments is `.front` for front-facing camera. I changed this to `.back`. This successfully gives me the rear-facing camera. However, the recognition region seems a little bit choppy, and as soon as it fixates on a face in the image, Xcode reports the error:

```
VisionFaceTrack[877:54517] [ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

In other words, the program crashes when a face is recognized, it seems. Clearly there is more to this than simply changing the constant used. Perhaps there is a buffer somewhere with the wrong size, or a wrong resolution. May I have help figuring out what may be wrong here?

A better solution would also include information about how to achieve this with arkit's camera feed, but I'm pretty sure it's the same idea with the `CVPixelBuffer`.

How would I adapt this example to use the rear camera?

EDIT: I think the issue is that my device has too little memory to support the algorithm using the back camera, as the back camera has a higher resolution.

However, even on another higher performance device, the tracking quality is pretty bad. --yet the vision algorithm only needs raw images, doesn't it? In that case, shouldn't this work? I can't find any examples online of using the back camera for face tracking.

Comment: Yup, I've tried this with my iPhone 11 Pro, and It works good enough. The code which selects the formats uses the highest possible resolution. Maybe you can do another kind of filtering to reduce the resolution size.

Comment: @Cerovec actually on an ipad even it seems to perform really poorly. The box and its orientation are all over the place. Besides changing .front to .back, did you do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I adapted the sample to make it work on my iPad Pro.

---

1) Download the sample project from here: [Tracking the User’s Face in Real Time.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time)

---

2) Change the function which loads the front facing camera to use back facing. Rename it to `configureBackCamera` and call this method `setupAVCaptureSession`:

```
fileprivate func configureBackCamera(for captureSession: AVCaptureSession) throws -> (device: AVCaptureDevice, resolution: CGSize) {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)

    if let device = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first {
        if let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
            if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
            }

            if let highestResolution = self.highestResolution420Format(for: device) {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.activeFormat = highestResolution.format
                device.unlockForConfiguration()

                return (device, highestResolution.resolution)
            }
        }
    }

    throw NSError(domain: "ViewController", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
}
```

---

3) Change the implementation of the method `highestResolution420Format`. The problem is, now that the back-facing camera is used, you have access to formats with much higher resolution than with front-facing camera, which can impact the performance of the tracking. You need to adapt to your use case, but here's an example of limiting the resolution to 1080p.

```c
fileprivate func highestResolution420Format(for device: AVCaptureDevice) -> (format: AVCaptureDevice.Format, resolution: CGSize)? {
    var highestResolutionFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format? = nil
    var highestResolutionDimensions = CMVideoDimensions(width: 0, height: 0)

    for format in device.formats {
        let deviceFormat = format as AVCaptureDevice.Format

        let deviceFormatDescription = deviceFormat.formatDescription
        if CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(deviceFormatDescription) == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange {
            let candidateDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(deviceFormatDescription)
            if (candidateDimensions.height > 1080) {
                continue
            }
            if (highestResolutionFormat == nil) || (candidateDimensions.width > highestResolutionDimensions.width) {
                highestResolutionFormat = deviceFormat
                highestResolutionDimensions = candidateDimensions
            }
        }
    }

    if highestResolutionFormat != nil {
        let resolution = CGSize(width: CGFloat(highestResolutionDimensions.width), height: CGFloat(highestResolutionDimensions.height))
        return (highestResolutionFormat!, resolution)
    }

    return nil
}
```

---

4) Now the tracking will work, but the face positions will not be correct. The reason is that UI presentation is wrong, because original sample was designed for front facing cameras with mirrored display, while the back facing camera doesn't need mirroring.

In order to tweak for this, simply change `updateLayerGeometry()` method. Specifically, you need to change this:

```
// Scale and mirror the image to ensure upright presentation.
let affineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radiansForDegrees(rotation))
    .scaledBy(x: scaleX, y: -scaleY)
overlayLayer.setAffineTransform(affineTransform)
```

into this:

```
// Scale the image to ensure upright presentation.
let affineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radiansForDegrees(rotation))
    .scaledBy(x: -scaleX, y: -scaleY)
overlayLayer.setAffineTransform(affineTransform)
```

---

After this, the tracking should work and the results should be correct.

Comment: This works -- almost! When rotating to landscape view, the detection seems to be wrong again. I'm looking at lines such as "        // Rotate the layer into screen orientation.
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {" and "func exifOrientationForDeviceOrientation". I think these are related, but I'm not sure how to get this working. In my application, I will prefer the landscape view rather than portrait, but the sample application prefers portrait. Would you help look into this as well? Also, I thought this example would detect multiple faces, but it only seems to see one at a time.

Comment: EDIT: Actually I figured out the rotation part, I think, but if I have several faces in the camera view, the demo seems to bounce between them erratically. I thought this was meant to recognize multiple faces. How would I modify this code to get that working?

Comment: Seems to me that supporting multiple faces should be a part of a different question. It's not that simple as it seems, as it brings multiple questions in mind. What should happen when another face comes into the scene? What should happen when the tracker loses a face? And obviously this demo wasn't designed for supporting multiple faces, so there should be a different project setup.